# Trouble with formatting of OHAttributedLabel when parsing markup

Tags: ios, uilabel, nsattributedstring

In a property list I have a string like this:

```
<string>A |picture| is worth *1000\* words.</string>
```

Obviously "picture" should be italic and "1000" should be bold. I'm trying to display the text using [OHAttributedLabel](https://github.com/AliSoftware/OHAttributedLabel):

```
NSString *theString = [pListData objectForKey:@"theString"];

NSMutableAttributedString* attrStr = [OHASBasicMarkupParser attributedStringByProcessingMarkupInString:theString];

self.myLabel.attributedText = attrStr; //self.myLabel is a UILabel
```

And here is what I get:

[image]

Why are the attributed words displayed in a smaller font, and how do I fix this?

Comment: If you have solved that please answer your question, or else I can start a bounty

Answer (score 1):

I have deal with something like this before. So, this will help you. Also i have tested it for you and works fine :)

```
NSString *string = @"A |picture| is worth *1000* words.";

// Create an NSMutableAttributedString in order to be able to use the NSAttributedString+Attributes.h category
NSMutableAttributedString *attributedString = [NSMutableAttributedString attributedStringWithString:string];

// If using custom fonts, import all styles in the app and update the plist file
[attributedString setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:20.0]];

// Parse the markup and set the attributedText of the UILabel instance (no need to use the OHAttributedLabel subclass)
attributedString = [OHASBasicMarkupParser attributedStringByProcessingMarkupInAttributedString:attributedString];
label.attributedText = attributedString;
```

**EDIT:** The problem comes when using `-setFont:` after the calling `-attributedStringByProcessingMarkupInAttributedString`, since that would reset all the work done during parsing.

Comment: Hmm, this works for me too, but can you please elaborate a bit about how and why?

Comment: Iam afraid i don't understand your question. What do you mean how?

Comment: Nevermind, I think I know the problem - I will edit your answer and give you the bounty.